# iphone search swiping

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uipagecontrol

I am wanting to have half of a view taken up by a page control. The page control will allow the user to swipe from left to right on a selection of 5 different table view lists.

1. Is this possible?
2. What is the best approach.

Will each table view that will be put into the page control need its own controller? Or am i totally off the path.

The example i want it flow like is the screenshots of apps in the app store app details page. Except for screenshots i will be showing lists of data.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It sure is possible. Use a scroll view with paging enabled.

And you dont *need* to have separate controllers for each table view. You can handle multiple tables in a single TableViewDelegate, as all the delegate methods have the table view a parameter.

Check [PageControl](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/PageControl/Introduction/Intro.html) and [ScrollViewSuit](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/ScrollViewSuite/Introduction/Intro.html) code samples.

And about covering half the view, well, your scroll view can be any size.